# VBA passing an array from a 2D array to a sub

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a function which collects which months are ticked in a user form, containing checkboxes:

```
Function get_entries() As Boolean()
```

This returns a 2D boolean array(4, 11) representing 5 x 12 check boxes, which in turn represents months that are selected from a userform

In my main function:

```
Dim montharr() As Boolean
montharr = get_entries()

Call myfunc1(montharr(0))
Call myotherfunc(montharr(1))
Call myotherfunc(montharr(2))
Call myotherfunc(montharr(3))
Call myotherfunc(montharr(4))
```

I can't pass in the individual arrays of 12 elements to the subs successfully. I have tried declaring items as variants too but this isn't working and have spent ages trying to get this to work. Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: you should create new _1D_ array with values `montharr(0,1)`, `montharr(0,2)` and so on and pass it in the `myotherfunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to "slice" a 2-D array:

```
Sub ArraySlicing()

Dim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 5)
Dim slice
Dim x, y
Dim a As Application

    For y = 1 To 5
    For x = 1 To 5
        arr(y, x) = "R" & y & ":C" & x
    Next x
    Next y

    Set a = Application

    'get first "column"
    slice = a.Transpose(a.Index(arr, 0, 1))
    Debug.Print Join(slice, ", ")

    'get second "row" (note double transpose)
    slice = a.Transpose(a.Transpose(a.Index(arr, 2, 0)))
    Debug.Print Join(slice, ", ")

End Sub
```

`Index()` gives you a 2-d array - (x,1) or (1,x) - `Transpose()` will convert that to a 1-d array.